# how to use self joins to retrieve data from a single table

Tags: sql

i have table like this

```
id     name     pid
101   Animal    null
102   Dog       101
103   pug       102
```

i want animal>dog>pug

Comment: What RDBMS are you using??

Comment: Just three levels, or an arbitrary number of levels?  Arbitrary is hard without recursive queries, such as recursive common table expressions or CTEs.  Also, is that a single row of output?  Which DBMS does make a big difference here.

Answer (score 0):

I Think Something like this works for you,as I don't know about your RDBMS maybe it needs some changes

```
WITH  NewAnimal
        AS (SELECT  CAST((a.Desc + '>' + t.Name) AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS "Desc"
             FROM    Table AS t
             JOIN NewAnimal AS a
             ON t.PID = a.id
           )
SELECT * FROM NewAnimal
```